# Changes in h5 file arent refelcted in xdmf file

Tags: python, h5py, paraview, hdf

Hello I was given an h5 file with an xdmf file associated with it. The visualization looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G24Od.png). Here the color is just the feature ID. I wanted to add some data to the h5 file to be able to visualize it in paraview. The newly added data does not appear in the paraview although clearly being there when using [hdfview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMZsH.png). The data I'm trying to add are the ones titled engineering stress and true stress. The only difference I noticed is that the number of attributes for these is zero while it's 5 for the rest but I dont know what to do with that information.

Here's the code I currently have set up:

```
nf_product = h5py.File(filename,"a")

e_princ = np.empty((280,150,280,3))

t_princ = e_princ

for i in tqdm(range(grain_count)):
    
    a = np.where(feature_ID == i+1)
    e_princ[a,0] = eng_stress[i,0]
    e_princ[a,1] = eng_stress[i,1]
    e_princ[a,2] = eng_stress[i,2]

    
    t_princ[a,0] = true_stress[i,0]
    t_princ[a,1] = true_stress[i,1]
    t_princ[a,2] = true_stress[i,2]

EngineeringStress = nf_product.create_dataset('DataContainers/nfHEDM/CellData/EngineeringStressPrinciple',data=np.float32(e_princ))
TrueStress = nf_product.create_dataset('DataContainers/nfHEDM/CellData/TrueStressPrinciple',data=np.float32(t_princ))
```

I am new to using h5 and xdmf files so I may be going about this entirely wrong but the way I understand it is an xdmf file acts as a pointer to the data in the h5 file so I can't understand why the new data doesnt appear in paraview.

Answer (score 0):

First, did you close the file with`nf_product.close()`? If not, new datasets may not have been flushed from memory. You may also need to flush the buffers with`nf_product.flush()` Better, use the Python `with / as:` file context manager and it is done automatically.
Next, you can simply use `data=e_princ` (and `t_princ`), there is no need to cast a numpy array to a numpy array.
Finally, verify the values in `e_princ` and `t_princ`. I think will be the same because they reference the same numpy object. You need to create `t_princ` as an empty array, the same as `e_princ`. Also they have 4 indices, and you only have 2 when you populate them with `[a,0]`. Be sure that works as expected.

Comment: a is a three element array so all four indices are being populated
the datasets are being added correctly (can view them in hdfview) just not in paraview